# RESTful Services in CodeIgniter, how to return empty array

Tags: codeigniter

I'm using RESTful Services in codeigniter,

(http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/working-with-restful-services-in-codeigniter-2/)

but I don't know how to return empty **array**.

I tried,

```
$this->response([], 200); // it return nothing
```

and

```
$this->response([[]], 200); // it return [[]]
```

I want to return **[]** only,

anybody know how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

here you go:

```
$this->response(array(), 200);
```

Comment: $this->response([], 200); // it return nothing

Answer (score 0):

Simply return:

```
$newarr = array();  
$this->response($newarr, 200);
```

Comment: $this->response([], 200); // it return nothing

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly, but I could solve with,

```
$this->response(array('result' => array());
```

it returns,

```
result:[]
```